# Resize the content in div with the drag

Tags: javascript, html, resize, drag

I am trying to drag and resize the div layer. And i am able to do that perfectly. But the issue is i am unable to apply resize effect to the content in the div. I tried applying same to the img element directly and it allows me to drag the element around but doesn't let me resize it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwV8g/1/

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwV8g/18/

Comment: Thank you so much! You are such a life saver

Comment: Ahh but now i have run into another problem. When i add another element dynamically the old one gets resized with it because both have same id. And I don't know how to give it an id dynamically and also parse that into function so that it works smoothly.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwV8g/19/