# jQuery resizable - Can we use this way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Normally jQuery resizeable expects element to be a direct child of resizeable to work, like this,

```
            <div id="resizeable">
                <div class="handler">
```

But can we have it like this ?

```
            <div class="handler">                 
            <div id="resizeable">
               <div id="head"> </div....
```

When I try 2nd approach just doesn't work..

Is there any work around ? I am trying to make a horizontal split but nothing seems to work, need it to work on IE-8 as well

Comment: why closing it ? please explain, I will improve the question ?

Comment: jQuery.Resizable inserts the handle divs  itself, n, w, e, s  -- as configured. It doesnt provide a template that you can alter. If you wanna go that deep you may want to fork the resizable module and change the way it deals with handles

Comment: Look at this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958419/custom-resizable-handles-in-jquery-ui

Comment: The question is clear, the issue is the library does not support it.

Comment: I think this is what i was really looking for, but it never going to work with resizeable easily - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061414/resize-elements-by-dragging-divider-handler  - there are few issues but I will fix them up tomorrow morning